# Define gulp task inside a callback from filesystem.readdir

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, gulp

I have to read the name of the first folder from a directory. Depend on that folder, I want to define the gulp tasks. As soon I define a task inside the callback function, the tasks doesn't get defined. I use Gulp 4

```
const fs = require('fs');
const gulp = require('gulp');

fs.readdir('Packages/Sites', function (error, files) {
    if (error) {
        return;
    }
    console.log('test');
    gulp.task('test', function(callback) {
        callback();
    });
});
```

The console log the 'test', bet the function 'test' doesn't get defined. Is there a way to get this running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution: If I use `readdirSync` everything works like a charm.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const siteFolder = fs.readdirSync('Packages/Sites')['0'];
```